# Chrome Extension With Service Account Identity

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api

I have developed an extension that uses chrome.identity.getAuthToken to connect to any logged in user.

I wanted to do kind of the same thing to Service Accounts. I saw the steps of Adding Service Account Credentials to use them. But looked like to be only connected to a specific Service Account.

I didn't know how to use the file installed as well, that has private_key_id -public key- client_email - client_id and "type": "service_account".

In normal user authentication I needed the client_id and extension id only.

Comment: not sure what your question is

Comment: how to authenticate with service account in chrome extensions.
So when using for example: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token=*****

I would get the service account's files not just the admin user's files.